# Avoid useState hook to run on initialisation

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, rxjs

I have a simple button, which subscribes and unsubscribes onPress()

```
<Button
      onPress={() => setRunning(running => !running)}
      title={running ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}
/>
```

But when I initialise my state, it runs the useState function which is fatal, because I can't unsubscribe from something I haven't been subscribed too.

```
const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);

useState(() => {
  if (running) {
    subscription.subscribe(...)
  } else {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
});
```

how can I avoid that useState ran unless I pressed the button?

Comment: Feels like an XY problem here. What is `subscription`? Perhaps you should check if `subscription` is subscribable to in the else block.

Comment: Subscription is from rxjs and reading sensor data from my phone.

Comment: You may find [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/reactive-programming-with-react-and-rxjs-88d2789e408a) interesting. It talks about rxJs and React.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you see that function get run is that that's what [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) **does**, it accepts the initial state and, if that's a function, it runs the function to get the initial state (on mount only).

You don't use `useState` for (side) effects like subscribing to things, that's just fundamentally not what it's for. For (side) effects, generally you use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (running) {
        subscription.subscribe(/*...*/)
        return () => {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        };
    }
}, [running]);
```

That does this:

- Any time `running` changes, it runs the function you pass it.
- If `running` is true at that point, it subscribes to the thing and returns a [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) that will unsubscribe from it.
- The next time `running` changes, or when the component is unmounted, the cleanup callback is called, doing the unsubscription.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const subscription = {
    subscribe() {
        console.log("subscribed");
    },
    unsubscribe() {
        console.log("unsubscribe");
    }
};

const Example = () => {
    const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (running) {
            subscription.subscribe(/*...*/)
            return () => {
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            };
        }
    }, [running]);

    return <input type="button" value={running ? "stop" : "run"} onClick={() => setRunning(r => !r)} />;
};

const App = () => {
    const [showExample, setShowExample] = useState(true);

    return <div>
        {showExample ? <Example /> : <em>(example hidden)</em>}
        <div>
            <label>
                <input
                    type="button"
                    value="show/hide example"
                    onClick={() => setShowExample(e => !e)}
                />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Another option is to subscribe/unsubscribe in the button click handler, but you'd still need a `useEffect` cleanup callback to ensure you unsubscribe on unmount. (Which can be tricky, because you can't use the `running` flag to determine whether to do it, because the cleanup function will close over a stale copy of it. For that you might need a ref.)